# "Pero te veo igual."

Tags: traducción, sintaxis

I saw this sentence: "Pero yo a ti te veo igual."

Assuming that's correct, would the following be correct? Would it have the same meaning?

"Pero te veo igual."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indeed it has the same meaning.

While "*Pero te veo igual*" is succinct and both subject and direct object of the sentence are implied, the second form makes them explicit for emphasis.

This sort of explicit or redundant constructs are frequently used in South America; this particular instance is common usage in Peru, Honduras and El Salvador. In Venezuela also, however, the formal mode: "*Pero yo a usted, le veo igual*" would be used there.

Comment: This is the same everywhere they speak Spanish. Te veo igual/Te veo de/con buena salud/Te veo feliz, etc. etc. etc,

Answer (score 3):

*Pero yo a ti te veo igual*
*Pero te veo igual*

Both sentence means the same as *te* and *a ti* are equal and you can omit *a ti* but not te.

Ambas oraciones significan lo mismo ya que *te* y *a ti* son sintácticamente la misma cosa.

Comment: I think that the usage of TE here is for the who of the action